# What is the maximum recommended file size I should load using NSData dataWithContentsOfURL?

Tags: ios, nsdata

The iOS documentation for dataWithContentsOfURL (https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSData_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/clm/NSData/dataWithContentsOfURL:) suggests

> "This method is ideal for converting data:// URLs to NSData objects,
>   and can also be used for reading short files synchronously"

How long is a short file in this case?

Answer (score 0):

It blocks the main thread because the mode of communication is in synchronous fashion. So, before user identify the block in UI, you should download the file. It should not be more than few kbs. There is no such defined rule for same. However as a better practice , one should always go with connection APIs if file size is greater than 10 kbs.

Comment: I'm using it to load a file from the device (which I've previously downloaded using NSURLSession). I'm looking for clarification on the filesize, is it 10s of KB, 100s of KB, MBs?

Comment: I checked with 100KB and it works fine. Beyond it, it starts blocking UI for observable amount of time.